# Format Codes in my function

Tags: c, sdl, string-formatting, c-strings

In C/C++, is there a way to write my function so that I can use format codes to print information easier? The function draws text to the screen with SDL, so I can't pass in a C++ string; it has to be a char array.

Comment: You could use va_args to mimick what `printf` does with `%` codes and print into a buffer and display that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can convert a c++ string to a char array using `myString.c_str()`.

Also, you can use sprintf() with format codes to produce a string. Then you can draw that string using SDL. For example:

```
char myString[1024];
sprintf(myString, "Hello my name is %s", "foo");
draw_using_SDL(myString);
```